# iCloud Backup: How Does Turning off an App Affect The Backup?

Tags: icloud, backup

In order to complete the backup for my iPad, I needed to disable a few applications in the backup settings in order to allow it to fit within my available iCould space. This is not an issue as the data for these apps is actually already stored and backed-up elsewhere (or I just don’t care). My question however is:

When I turn off an app in the backup settings, does that just remove the application data from the backup, or is it the entire application? I.e. Would I need to manually re-install the applications that are disabled when restoring from a backup, or just the data?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud backup only backs up your specific data that is stored in the application. The actual application bundle is not stored in the backup itself. Anything that is available from any of the Apple app or other content stores is re-downloaded at the point in time that you do a restore.

This KB [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428) details what is included in an iCloud backup.

Comment: If I, for example, disable backup of Microsoft Teams, Microsoft Teams WILL be installed on a new iPad that I restore via iCloud backups, but all the accounts and settings of Microsoft teams will be gone. Is this correct? Also, if I do a direct (non-cloud) transfer, will it allow me to retain my Teams data without consuming iCloud? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it will restore the app, but not any of the settings or data that was in it before the restore.